# Getting div by class name and returning it in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to inject some javascript into a web page using a very simple js script:

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("main").innerHTML;
alert(c);
```

I want to set an alert of the text (and only the text) in the div with class="main". Currently the script is making an alert pop up saying 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong, the class name is definitely correct, and I have searched stackoverflow and other sources, having experimented with .innerHTML and .textContent but nothing seems to be able to simply return a var of text.

Comment: since u've tagged jquery, you can use $('.main').text(); if you want the text  and $('.main').html() if u want the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are returning a [set of nodes (HTMLCollection)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). All elements with the class "main" ([getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)). For example, this will show you the first element's innerHTML

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0].innerHTML;
alert(c);
```

However, a more standardized approach for this would be to use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) like this

```
var c = document.querySelector(".main").innerHTML;
alert(c);
```

Answer (score 4):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array like object. There is no `innerHTML` property on it. You need to either act on all the divs returned or a specific one. See docs for further examples. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array because there could be multiple classes with the same class name.

Try doing

```
var c = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0].innerHTML;
alert(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.getElementsByClassName) it returns an [`array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray)(in this case a group of elements) which you have to define an offset to mark which one of the elements you want to use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0].innerHTML;//0 returns the first element
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a0a9kvp4/1/)

If you want to select all the elements of the class, the easiest way is to use a loop:

```
    var element =document.getElementsByClassName("main");
    for($i=0;$i<=element.length;$i++){
       alert(element[$i].innerHTML);
    }
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a0a9kvp4/)